# referencing xproj from csproj

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

I've added reference from `csproj` to `xproj` in visual studio.

I see library in references and path to dll is correct. Intelisens work but compile not work with error:

```
the type could not be found.
```

How do I put into operation this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a single source project with full .net, PCL and dotnet core assemblies build from same C# source?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38206209/create-a-single-source-project-with-full-net-pcl-and-dotnet-core-assemblies-bu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly reference xproj project from csproj, only the other way around.

What you can do is create a nuget package from xproj with `dotnet pack` (or `dnu pack`, if you're using `rc1`) and then install that nuget in csproj.