# Referencing .NET Core library in .NET 4.5.2

Tags: .net, .net-core

Is it possible to reference a .NET Core library in a .NET 4.5.2 project? I'm using the latest rc of .NET Core and want to use the same library for my WPF project and my .NET Core Web API. If I want to add the reference to my project this window is shown:

[image]

I also tried to upgrade my WPF project to 4.6.1 but this doesn't changes anything.

**Update**
It is now possible with Core 2.0

Comment: What is KBSLauncherLibCore?

Comment: This is the core library I want to reference in my WPF project

Comment: Does the answer from Gary Holland in this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33810504/reference-a-net-core-library-in-a-net-4-6-project

Comment: Compile to a NuGet package and then consume it in the WPF.

Comment: It is not possible.
You can referencing is as nuget.
[More info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38007890/referencing-xproj-from-csproj)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of now (June 2016), there are two steps required:

1. Make sure your .NET Core project is building for `net452` or `netstandard1.2` (which includes `net452` according to the [docs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md#mapping-the-net-platform-standard-to-platforms)). This will ensure that your project will output a binary that your .NET 4.5.2 project can use.
2. Create a nuget package from your .NET Core project with `dotnet pack`. Host this [locally](https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds) or on MyGet. Referencing this package in your .NET 4.5.2 application will pull in the correct binary!

Visual Studio will apparently be able to directly reference .NET Core projects from csproj projects in the future, but for now, step 2 is the best workaround I've found.

Answer (score 0):

I answered that here: [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50284068/828184)

But my answer is for at least 4.6.2. If it works bellow that you have to try or upgrade if possible

Comment: It's possible since Core 2.0 (see the edit in the OP)