# How to reference a dotNet Core project?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core

I want to reference a dotNet Core project to a WPF project.

My WPF project is using the v4.6.2 dotNet Framework and my dotNet Core project is using the v1.6 dotNet Standard.

When I try to reference it, I get this error:

[image: A reference to 'ClassLibrary' could not be added. An assembly must have a 'dll' or 'exe' extension in order to be referenced.]

Comment: Why not create a .net standard library? That would be able to be referenced by .NET Framework and .NET Core applications.

Answer (score 2):

v1.6 .Net Core isn't compatible with v4.6.2 .Net according to the [docs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md#mapping-the-net-platform-standard-to-platforms).

So I changed it to v1.5 .Net Core.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to be up2date. At least the docs say the repo has moved to .net Standard

Answer (score 0):

I found this [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/qc2WFaMfdp8). The easiest way is to write this in the *.csproj

```
<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.0;net462</TargetFrameworks>
```

instead of this

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
```

Important notes: 
don't forget the **extra s** in targetframework**S**. You should at least have Runtime and DevPack of .NET Core 4.6.2.([get it here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/all)). After the change you often have to right click unload and then right click reload the project.

Comment: Go with netstandard if you are building a libraries so that they can be used in dotnet core as well as dot net framework. Sharing a link with full compatibility chart      https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard